# System.Zip.TZipFile.ExtractZipFile throws error with certain files. Why?

Tags: delphi, zip, delphi-10-seattle

When extracting a ZIP file with `System.Zip.TZipFile`:

```
System.Zip.TZipFile.ExtractZipFile('C:\test.zip', 'R:\_TEST\');
```

for a specific ZIP file I get this error message box:

> Stream read error.

Why?

The zip file which to reproduce the error, base64 encoded:

UEsDBC0ACAAIAHyDiEcAAAAA//////////8WABQATmV1ZXMgVGV4dGRva3VtZW50LnR4dAEAEAAA AAAAAAAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAwBQSwcIAAAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABQSwECLQstAAgACAB8g4hH AAAAAP//////////FgA4AAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAATmV1ZXMgVGV4dGRva3VtZW50LnR4dAEAEAAA AAAAAAAAAAIAAAAAAAAACgAgAAAAAAABABgA1LFkAs0x0QHUsWQCzTHRAdSxZALNMdEBUEsFBgAA AAABAAEAfAAAAGIAAAAAAA==

Go to http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

Decode this to your local storage as test.zip (don't change the character set)

The MD5 of the decoded binary file must be:

7357193E8F27FE1FB5AF2B8B6AF1F24C

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've provided an example which allows to reproduce the error.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Could you reproduce the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Reference*: [The structure of a PKZip file
by Florian Buchholz](https://users.cs.jmu.edu/buchhofp/forensics/formats/pkzip.html).

Your ZIP file is stored using the ZIP64 extended variant of the format. The Delphi ZIP code does not support ZIP64.

I deduced that the file was ZIP64 by looking at the local file header. The compressed and uncompressed size fields are both `0xffffffff`. From the reference above:

- **Compressed size**: if archive is in ZIP64 format, this filed is 0xffffffff and the length is stored in the extra field
- **Uncompressed size**: if archive is in ZIP64 format, this filed is 0xffffffff and the length is stored in the extra field

For the library to support ZIP64 it needs to detect these conditions and read the 64 bit values out of the additional headers. The Delphi code does not and attempts to read `0xffffffff` bytes that are not there.

You will need to find a different ZIP file library, one that supports ZIP64, in order to operate on such a ZIP file. Alternatively, you could side-step the problem if you could arrange that whatever creates the ZIP files uses the plain ZIP format.

Comment: Interestingly, `System.Zip.TZipFile.IsValid` returns TRUE for this same ZIP file which creates an error when extracting. This is inconsistent.

Comment: I don't see an inconsistency. This is just an unsupported format.

Comment: In other words, the library can't tell you that it's invalid since has been written in complete ignorance of ZIP64. It would be pretty easy to add ZIP64 support I think. But if I were you I'd switch to abbrevia.

Comment: I've tested Abbrevia now and it works very well (of course even with the above ZIP file). - So why does Embarcadero not add ZIP64 support to `System.Zip`, maybe with your help?

Comment: I don't know. It's just one more thing I guess. Perhaps you might submit an issue to quality portal. Anyway, I think this is all done now right?

Comment: Yes, please remove the close thing.

Comment: That wasn't me. It doesn't matter. It was cast when the question was not answerable. It's all fine now.